# How to stay on the same page without refreshing after the user cancels leaving?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage test.php with:

- a form
- a "Submit" button to send the answers to the form;
- a "Leave" button to allow the user to leave the page (and go to 'leave.php') without filling the form;
- a Controller which controls the data when the user clicks on Submit, and redirects elsewhere when everything is correct.

I would like the user to confirm that (s)he wants to leave before redirecting. Here is my code so far:

```js
function confirmation(){
  var result = confirm("Do you really want to leave this page?");
  if(result){
    window.location = 'leave.php';
  }
  else{
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

```html
  

<form method="post" action="test.php">
     <input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" placeholder="Type your answer here">
     <input type="submit" name="submit_answer" value="Submit your answer">
     <input type="submit" name="leave" value="Leave this page" onClick="return confirmation();">
</form>
```

I have two problems:

1. The code does not redirect to leave.php when the user confirms that (s)he wants to leave, but it refreshes the current page. How can I fix that?
2. When the user selects Cancel in the confirmation box, the page test.php is reloaded and the data is lost: that is, the textbox is empty even if the user wrote something before clicking on Leave. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: for 2. change to <input type="button" name="leave", solves also 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can submit the form using JavaScript. First, change both buttons to `type="button"`. Using `type="submit"` submits your button causing your errors. Then write a simple function to submit the form.

```js
function confirmation(){
  var result = confirm("Do you really want to leave this page?");
  if(result){
    window.location = 'leave.php';
  }
  else{
    return FALSE;
  }
}

function submitForm(){
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  form.submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" action="test.php">
     <input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" placeholder="Type your answer here">
     <input type="button" name="submit_answer" value="Submit your answer" onClick="submitForm()">
     <input type="button" name="leave" value="Leave this page" onClick="return confirmation();">
</form>
```

Comment: Actually, on reviewing the question, you don't even need the submit function (although it can be useful for pre-submit handling), just change the leave button to type `button`

Comment: Awesome. It works like a charm. Thank you! If I may, can I ask you why my solution did not work?

Comment: Your button is type `submit` so after the `confirmation()` function is called, it submits, but you set it to return `false` so it refreshes the form.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to Submit-Buttons each of them will submit your form. So you've got a conflict between the redirection to `"test.php"` and `"leave.php"`. In this case, the action from the form comes always first.

```js
function confirmation(){
    var result = confirm("Do you really want to leave this page?");
    if(result){
        window.location = 'leave.php';
    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

```html
  

<form method="post" action="test.php">
     <input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" placeholder="Type your answer here">
     <input type="submit" name="submit_answer" value="Submit your answer">
     <input type="button" name="leave" value="Leave this page" onClick="return confirmation();">
</form>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for the fix and for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version. I believe the issue was with the return statement, "return confirmation()":

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
     <input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" placeholder="Type your answer here">
     <input type="submit" name="submit_answer" value="Submit your answer">
     <input type="submit" name="leave" value="Leave this page" onClick="confirmation(); return false;">
</form>
<script>
  function confirmation(e){
      var result = confirm("Do you really want to leave this page?");
      if (result) {
        window.location = '/leave.php';
      } else {
          return FALSE;
      }
  }
</script>
```